# Where is it best to put postmodifier?

Tags: phrasing

which is better written?

> 1.The plan is to remove books **from the library** that haven’t been borrowed in five years to make space for new books.
>
> 2.The plan is to remove **from the library** books that haven’t been borrowed in five years to make space for new books.
>
> 3.The plan is to remove books that haven't been borrowed in five years **from the library** to make space for new books.

I am not asking for a mere proofwriting. I often come acroos this kind of situation: I want to make **books** close to **that clause**, while **remove** close to **from**, but I am afraid senetence 2 may sound a bit unnatural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1... remove books *from the library* that haven’t been borrowed ...

> 2... remove *from the library* books that haven’t been borrowed ...

> 3... remove books that haven't been borrowed in five years *from the library* ...

Sure, (2) is clear and is my preferred choice. The relative clause *that haven’t been borrowed* is right after its antecedent.

The other two versions are acceptable too.

Comment: If you have a short phrase/clause/element and a long one it's common to put the short one "from the library" first, as in 2.

Comment: As Seowjooheng implies, it's the books that haven't been borrowed, not the library .(Sentence (1) is not likely to be misunderstood, but (2) is better).

Comment: I would guess 3 would be most common in conversation. 2 sounds like it has been carefully written.

Answer (score -1):

3. 

The important part is the object being acted upon: the book. The second most important part is why it is being acted upon. The location is far less important.